# Deploying Dotnet Core Entity framework migrations

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, octopus-deploy

I am working on a fresh .netcore api project. I am trying to deploy the application using octopus.

I need help on executing the migrations from command line and I am not getting a lot of help. If some one can help me it will really help.

Here is what I have tried so far:
I have taken help of the following link to come up with a solution but it does not really work for me.

https://www.benday.com/2017/03/17/deploy-entity-framework-core-migrations-from-a-dll/

I had to make few modifications to the script in order to set the dll paths right. 
Here is how it is looking now

```
set EfMigrationsNamespace=%Dummy.WebAPI 
set EfMigrationsDllName=%Dummy.WebAPI.deps.dll 
set EfMigrationsDllDepsJson=%Dummy.WebAPI.deps.json 
set EfMigrationsStartupAssembly=%Dummy.Data.dll 
set DllDir=%cd% 
set PathToNuGetPackages=%USERPROFILE%\.nuget\packages 
set PathToEfDll=%PathToNuGetPackages%\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools\1.1.1\tools\netcoreapp1.0\ef.dll
ECHO %PathToEfDll%

dotnet exec --depsfile .\%EfMigrationsDllDepsJson% --additionalprobingpath %PathToNuGetPackages% %PathToEfDll% database update --assembly .\%EfMigrationsDllName% --startup-assembly .\%EfMigrationsStartupAssembly% --project-dir . --content-root %DllDir% --data-dir %DllDir% --verbose --root-namespace %EfMigrationsNamespace%
```

However the script throws index oput of bound error which is very confusing to me. Here is the exception.

System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array. 
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.CommandLine.CommandLineApplication.ParseOption(Boolean isLongOption, CommandLineApplication c 
ommand, String[] args, Int32& index, CommandOption& option) 
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.CommandLine.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args) 
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Program.Main(String[] args) 
Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Any clue to this error? Or if I should take any other approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the `dotnet exec` command is not build correctly, seeing as it has problems parsing your commands.

I'm using dotnet core 2-preview and had to change the batch file slightly. I now works for me:

```
set EfMigrationsNamespace=%1
set EfMigrationsDllName=%1.dll
set EfMigrationsDllDepsJson=%1.deps.json
set DllDir=%cd%
set PathToNuGetPackages=%USERPROFILE%\.nuget\packages
set PathToEfDll=%PathToNuGetPackages%\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools\2.0.0-preview2-final\tools\netcoreapp2.0\ef.dll

dotnet exec --depsfile .\%EfMigrationsDllDepsJson% --additionalprobingpath %PathToNuGetPackages% %PathToEfDll% database update --assembly .\%EfMigrationsDllName% --startup-assembly .\%EfMigrationsDllName% --project-dir . --data-dir %DllDir% --verbose --root-namespace %EfMigrationsNamespace%
```

Comment: This certainly works for me. I think the problem I am having is to use this script while deploying into servers. the PathToNuGetPackages and PathToEfDll values could be different in different servers or environments. .nuget folder is certainly not available in the werver 2012 that I am using neigher any 2.0 packages are deployed under my profile.